# What are some good Nginx rate limits for WordPress websites?

Tags: nginx, security, wordpress, rate-limiting

We are optimizing the default configuration for SlickStack, and looking for some good values to recommend to users for the `limit_req` and `limit_conn` settings in Nginx.

There are plenty of tutorials around the web, but the settings used are very random.

Most of the time, something like `rate=1r/s` with `burst=1 nodelay` is used for URIs like `/wp-login.php` however this seems too liberal for strong security.

There's also not much discussion about rate-limiting the entire server/website, `.php` files, and so forth.

The `limit_conn` feature is rarely mentioned, and `limit_rate` as well.

I'm hoping to start a thread about some possible settings for typical WordPress websites, with a special nod toward cloud servers or non-shared hosting environments, keeping in mind that these settings should be adjusted depending on your expected traffic levels and otherwise...

Comment: Most rate limiting solutions deal with a single login page or otherwise, and fail to consider the large number of "requests" that a CMS might require, and how different parts of the website might need different rate limits. Here's an example from 2015 dealing with a website built on Ruby: https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/request-limit-calculation/242388

Comment: The SE network is not a place for discussions. If you want discussions you need to ask somewhere else. The answer to your question boils down to benchmark and evaluate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you do load testing and capacity planning for web sites?](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/1091683/rate-limiting-only-the-home-page-with-nginx-limit-req-zone

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/346432/nginx-proper-use-of-limit-req-zone-and-limit-req

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/1105069/nginx-ratelimit-on-all-files

Comment: I don't see how a general answer is possible. It has to be tailored to each sites expected and normal traffic.

Comment: Focus on your question. Calling other users names simply doesn't work. There's no conspiracy, there's no power tripping. Nor do I see how your answer is universally applicable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of inaccurate information online about rate-limiting in WordPress. Specifically, many people assume that 1 request = 1 page load, which is wrong. There is also significant misinformation about what the per second `/s` and per minute `/m` directives mean and what the results will be...

The average WordPress website might require 50-100+ "requests" for a single page load, because of all the different PHP, JS, CSS, etc assets being loaded.

Here are some possible settings for `limit_req` and `limit_conn` for a typical WordPress site:

For `/wp-login.php` rate-limit:

- `limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=wplogin:10m rate=1r/s;`
- `limit_req zone=wplogin burst=1 nodelay`

For server-wide (e.g. `location /` in server block):

- `limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=sitewide:10m rate=50r/s;`
- `limit_req zone=sitewide burst=100 nodelay;`

I will add more later after more testing...